# Remove soft link but not the target

Tags: directory, symlink, rm

I have a directory that contains a link to another directory that I just created. I would like to remove the link but preserve the directory my link was pointing to. How do I do this?

```
> mkdir rgac
> ln -s /actual_dir_with_data/ /rgac/
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rm /rgac/actual_dir_with_data` should do nicely (you created a link probably called `actual_dir_with_data` in `/rgac`). Don't worry, `rm(1)` doesn't remove directories unless specifically told to do so. And you can then delete only `/rgac` by `rmdir /rgac` (see `rmdir(1)`).

Probably what you wanted to do was `ln -s /actual_dir_with_data /rgac`